# how to find repeater inside another repeater

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I want to find repeater inside the another repeater. But i m not able to find. My code is

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rep_test" runat="server">
     <ItemTemplate>
           <div id='h<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "ItemIndex") %>' class="header" onclick='ToggleDisplay(<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "ItemIndex") %>);'>
                    <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ID")%>
           </div>
           <div id='d<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "ItemIndex") %>' class="details">
           <asp:Repeater ID="rep_hello" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "batchid")%><br />
                    <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ts")%><br />
                </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:Repeater>
                <%--    <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "batchid")%><br />
                    <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ts")%><br />--%>
            </div>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Define "find" in this case.  I can visually find it right there.  How are you trying to find it?  If you're using code, show the code and tell us what's happening when you debug through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example:

In **ItemDataBound** event handler:

```
protected void rep_test_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType ==  ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
  {
    (e.Item.FindControl("rep_hello") as Repeater).DataSource = YourOtherDataSource;      
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you put a repeater inside an item template of another repeater that means that every item of the main repeater (rep_test) will have a repeater inside it (rep_hello). So you actually need to find the repeater inside a repeaterItem. You can iterate trough all the nested repeaters like this:

```
foreach (RepeaterItem item in rep_test)
        Repeater rptr = (Repeater)item.FindControl("rep_hello");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using .FindControl(). In VB, it would be something like

```
Dim rpt as Repeater = rep_test.FindControl("rep_hello")
```

Comment: Unfortunately, for repeater-type controls, it doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when I see this kind of thing, you want to perform some event on all of the inner repeaters.  What I usually do is handle this kind of thing inside the ItemDataBound event.

Add an OnItemDataBound attribute to your Repeater.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rep_test" runat="server" 
OnItemDataBound="rep_test_ItemDataBound">
```

Then in the back end, add a handler, with a FindControl call.

```
protected void rptBasket_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || 
        e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
         Repeater innerRepeater = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("rep_hello");
         // Now your have your repeater...do what you want with it.
    }
}
```